# Use iPhone Camera's QR Code Scanner on Web App

Tags: iphone, camera, qr-code

I have implemented a couple different QR code readers on my website to use with a mobile device.  None of them work as well as the iPhone native camera.

I'd love to use the native camera app to scan QR codes. However, when opening the camera through HTML Media Capture like

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

the native QR scanner isn't active.  My guess is that because the camera is opening to create a file, there's no need for the QR scanner to load.

Is there a way to:

1) click a link to exit the browser and open the native camera app on the iPhone?

or

2) get the QR scanner to be included in the camera when opening the camera with the HTML Media Capture or another method?

Comment: Hi Brad, did you ever figure an elegant solution to your issue here? we are having the exact same problem, and would like to find a similar solution to what you were looking for.

Comment: Hey Cory,  shortly after the original post Chrome introduced a QR reader built into the browser so I no longer needed to exit the browser to open up the camera

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible to do that. You should use a library that could detect QR code from a file/image that the user will take